# Change password in ASP.NET Core 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

How to change user password by admin in Asp core 2.x ?

or Change password with sms code

My sample code:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(model);

var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
if (user == null)
    return RedirectToAction("Index");

if (model.smsCode == user.SmsCode)
{
    user.PasswordHash = model.NewPassword;

    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
    }
}
```

error: save unhash pass in db

Comment: The error tells you that the password needs to be hashed before saving. Saving cleartext passwords is a big no-no.

Comment: Are you trying to save a plain text password into the PasswordHash field? I would expect you would have to hash model.NewPassword before saving it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We should not update the **user.PasswordHash** with a plain text , we should use Hash instead .

```
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
        if(user == null){ /**/ }
        if (model.smsCode != user.SmsCode){ /**/}

        // compute the new hash string
        var newPassword = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user,newpass);
        user.PasswordHash = newPassword;
        var res = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        if (res.Succeeded) {/**/}
        else { /**/}
```